# What does zend; mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript

While going through a new project source code, I immediately noticed something unfamiliar:

```
function(){
   var data = {},
       init = function(){},
       zend;

   return ..

}
```

So, what is `zend;` ?

Comment: It looks like it's just declaring a variable called zend. Note the commas at the end of the previous two lines: this is just a continuation of the var line.

Comment: @emix has it correct. Notice the `,` after `init = funciton(){}` it's just a continuation of variable declaration.

Comment: Indent the code properly the the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

It has no special meaning. In this context, it is just a variable name.

The code is equivalent to:

```
var data = {};
var init = function(){};
var zend;
```